# Jomres Country code and flag not corresponding

Tags: component

Country codes and flags do not correspond. Where can I change the country codes?

I checked the mod-language (language switcher), but didn't find all the flags and countries.

Is there another folder where the flags and country codes are kept?

[image]

Comment: Have you asked your question or searched on the Jomres Forum? They are more likely to have seen the issue before and there may a solution already.

Comment: i did but was unfortunate, thanks